# What AT commands are required to register an IoT modem on Verizon?

Tags: iot, at-command, modem, cellular-network

I'm trying to troubleshoot a wireless modem that contains a Sierra MC73xx module.  Also, my SIM is from an MVNO that says it has enabled roaming on Verizon.

I run `AT+COPS=?` and can see the Verizon network:

> +COPS: (0,"T-Mobile","T-Mobile","310260",2),(0,"Verizon","Verizon","311480",7),(0,"T-Mobile","T-Mobile","310260",0),(0,"AT&T","AT&T","310410",7),(0,"AT&T","AT&T","310410",2),(0,"T-Mobile","T-Mobile","310260",7),,(0,1,2,3,4),(0,1,2)

However when I run `AT+COPS=1,2,311480` I can't seem to register on the network.

Are there other AT commands required to register a roaming SIM on the Verizon network?  BTW through testing I've been able to register on T-Mobile and AT&T.

Comment: http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcops-plmn-selection/

Answer (score 1):

In the PLMN scan result, there is only one Verizon network,
 (0,"Verizon","Verizon","311480",7). "7" indicates the radio access technology(RAT) and I remember 7 is LTE.

On the other hand, both AT&T and T-Mobile has 2G/3G coverage, i.e. RAT 0 and 2. In your successful registration, you probably see the RAT is 0 or 2. You can use at!gstatus to check RAT.

I suspect your SIM card cannot roaming in Verizon LTE network. Usually international roaming agreement does not cover LTE.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing you can check is if this carrier is in your SIM's forbidden list.  This can happen if your device tries to connect to a network and is denied.

For clearing this list, [see here](https://support.hologram.io/hc/en-us/articles/360035697373-Clear-the-FPLMN-forbidden-networks-list) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Verizon (nowadays, as of this response) is very particular about which modems may register to its towers.  Verizon certifies cellular modules before they're allowed to register and maintains a list of authorized IMEIs.

If your module's IMEI isn't on that list, it's not going to work.

Even using a Verizon SIM card on a Verizon-certified device, I couldn't connect one time.  I had to call Verizon and give them the expected IMEI for that SIM's ICCID so the tower knew what to expect ahead of time.  Then it worked.

I suppose that trying to connect through an agreement with an MVNO they wouldn't have you call Verizon and explicitly tell them the IMEI, but it would still need to be in an expected range of IMEIs that Verizon expects.

Verizon does this to assure that customers will have a consistent experience on their network as their LTE system uses frequencies (bands) that other carriers do not; they "certify" modules submitted to them by the manufacturers - give them a stamp of approval - the module has demonstrated the ability to operate according to Verizon's specifications.